# Selecting fields from multiple tables with Where and Substr

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause, substr

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I've been trying all week and can't find the problem.  I'm new to oracle so I'm hoping it's something easy I'm missing.  My script is below. I'm trying to pull students by criteria and the teacher they are with by criteria derived from the student info.

I'm receiving this error.

Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 1,087
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

```
set trimspool off
SET FEEDBACK off
SET TERMOUT off
SET HEAD OFF
spool C:\ADExport\exports\Transportation.txt
select    'Student_Number,FName,LName,SiteID,Grad_Year,EntryDate,Grade,Birthday,Homeroom,room,Track,Phone,DCID,Gender,PrevSchoolName,City,State,Zip,enroll_status,Mother,liveswith1,father,liveswith2,gaurd1fn,gaurd1ln,liveswith3,Relationship1,gaurd2fn,gaurd2ln,liveswith4,Relationship2,Address,Apt,teacherfirst,teacherlast,teacheremail' from dual;
select 
    s.student_number||','||
    s.first_name||','||
    s.last_name||','||
    s.schoolID||','||
    s.sched_yearofgraduation||','||
    s.entrydate||','||
    s.grade_level||','||
    s.dob||','||
    s.home_room||','||
    s.track||','||
    s.home_phone||','||
    s.dcid||','||
    s.gender||','||
    se.PrevSchoolName||','||
    s.city||','||
    s.state||','||
    s.zip||','||
    s.enroll_status||','||
    replace(s.mother,',','')||','||
    se.p1_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    replace(s.father,',','')||','||
    se.p2_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    se.p3_firstname||','||
    se.p3_lastname||','||
    se.p3_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    se.p3_relationshipToStu||','||
    se.p4_firstname||','||
    se.p4_lastname||','||
    se.p4_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    se.p4_relationshipToStu||','||
    s.street||','||
    (select
        t.first_name||','||
        t.last_name||','||
        t.email_addr||
    FROM teachers t
    Where t.homeschoolid in s.schoolid and t.room in SUBSTR(s.home_room, 6, 2))
    ''
FROM students s
INNER JOIN U_DEF_EXT_STUDENTS se ON s.dcid = se.studentsdcid 
Where s.enroll_status in (-1) and s.schoolid > 3 and s.schoolid <> 6;
Spool off;
exit;
```

Comment: Look at row: ``t.email_addr||`` there are extra ``||``. The ``||`` are probably missing before ``''``.

Comment: Aside from your error, it looks like you are trying to create a csv file of the output.  Instead of all the concatenations and literals, why not simply use the sqlplus directive 'set markup csv on'   Read about it in the docs, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-0AA910C4-C22A-4A9E-BE13-AAA059CC7919)

Comment: Thank you David, that was it!! I removed them and it worked.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a stray `||` after `t.email_addr`, and the line with `''` before the FROM clause shouldn't be there.

```
select
    s.student_number||','||
    s.first_name||','||
    s.last_name||','||
    s.schoolID||','||
    s.sched_yearofgraduation||','||
    s.entrydate||','||
    s.grade_level||','||
    s.dob||','||
    s.home_room||','||
    s.track||','||
    s.home_phone||','||
    s.dcid||','||
    s.gender||','||
    se.PrevSchoolName||','||
    s.city||','||
    s.state||','||
    s.zip||','||
    s.enroll_status||','||
    replace(s.mother,',','')||','||
    se.p1_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    replace(s.father,',','')||','||
    se.p2_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    se.p3_firstname||','||
    se.p3_lastname||','||
    se.p3_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    se.p3_relationshipToStu||','||
    se.p4_firstname||','||
    se.p4_lastname||','||
    se.p4_livesatphysicaladd||','||
    se.p4_relationshipToStu||','||
    s.street||','||
    (select
        t.first_name||','||
        t.last_name||','||
        t.email_addr
     from  teachers t
     where t.homeschoolid = s.schoolid
     and   t.room = substr(s.home_room,6,2))
from   students s
       join u_def_ext_students se on s.dcid = se.studentsdcid
where  s.enroll_status in (-1)
and    s.schoolid > 3
and    s.schoolid <> 6
/
```

I also changed a couple of `in`s to `=`. Change them back if you want to add a list of values.

I'm not sure what tool you are using that reported line 11, column 1,087. SQL*Plus reported line 37 which is

```
     from  teachers t
```

SQL*Plus 12.2 has a `set markup csv` option, SQL Developer has a `/* csv */` comment syntax, and other tools have their own ways of exporting data to text file, so depending on what you have, the above spooling and concatenation may not be needed.